How to custom bluetooth advertising data
I am deverloping bluetooth advertising on android. I need to set a advertiseData like this
adv_data_const[31] =
{
    0x02,
    0x01,
    0x06,
    0x03,
    0x02,
    0x50, 0xFD,
    0x17,
    0x16,
    0x50, 0xFD,
    0x41, 0x00,       //Frame Control
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

and scan response data like this
can_rsp_data_const[31] =
{   
    0x17,             // length
    0xFF,
    0xD0,
    0x07,
    0x00, //Encry Mode(8)
    0x00,0x00, //communication way bit0-mesh bit1-wifi bit2-zigbee bit3-NB
    0x00, //FLAG
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x03, //24
    0x09,
    0x54, 0x59,
};

to start advertising. When checking the AdvertiseData api, I see that it cant accept set from bytes array.
I want to set data for AdvertiseData as the same array above. Everyone help me to suggest the solution

This question is similar to: Is there any way to advertise raw data over BLE in Android?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
